# Exclude URL in Deeplinking Android

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-deep-link

Do we have any other alternative solution to exclude the few URL's expect using **android:pathPrefix** ?.

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking):

> You can add more attributes to further refine the type of URI that the activity accepts. For example, you might have multiple activities that accept similar URIs, but which differ simply based on the path name. In this case, use the `android:path` attribute or its `pathPattern` or `pathPrefix` variants to differentiate which activity the system should open for different URI paths.